# GifImageView in Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use a sample to play gifs in my app,

but start(), stop() and pause() methods not working.

sample: [enter link description here](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

nuget package: Install-Package Karamunting.Android.Koral.AndroidGifDrawable

This is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6ulD.png)

Thanks for helping me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO

That exception thrown because you casts wrong object to wrong Type (`GifDrawable`).

To achieve what you want, you have to get `Drawable` object first by accessing `GifImageView.Drawable` property and then cast it to `GifDrawable`.
Now you can access those methods (`.Stop()`, `.Start()`) correctly.

Sample code:

```cs
var gifImageView0 = FindViewById<GifImageView>(Resource.Id.gif6);

var stop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
stop.Click += (s, e) =>
{
    // 
    (gifImageView0.Drawable as GifDrawable)?.Stop();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

I have checked the **Karamunting.Android.Koral.AndroidGifDrawable** Nuget Package, it seems not providing the guides for Xamarin Android to invoke it. And there is only 721 downloads. After testing in my local site, it has many errors when using its methods shared from GitHub. I think it will need more time to solve problems about ***specified cast is not valid***.

[image]

**Therefore**, I will suggest that installing **[Refractored.GifImageView](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GifImageView-Xamarin.Android)** from JamesMontemagno. I have test that in local site, and it wroks so conveniently.And you can refer to **[its GitHub](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GifImageView-Xamarin.Android)** to know how to use in Xamarin Android.

Install it:

[image]

Sample code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    Felipecsl.GifImageViewLibrary.GifImageView gifImageView;
    //PL.DroidsOnRoids.Gif.GifImageView gifImageViewTrans;
    Button btnToggle;
    Button btnStart;
    Button btnStop;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        gifImageView = FindViewById<Felipecsl.GifImageViewLibrary.GifImageView>(Resource.Id.gifImageView);
        //gifImageViewTrans = FindViewById<PL.DroidsOnRoids.Gif.GifImageView>(Resource.Id.gifImageView2);
        btnToggle = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnToggle);
        btnStart = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnStart);
        btnStop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnStop);


        // From Drawable
        Stream input = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Drawable.timg);

        // You should convert the "input" into Byte Array 
        byte[] bytes = ConvertByteArray(input);

        gifImageView.SetBytes(bytes);
        gifImageView.StartAnimation();

        btnToggle.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (gifImageView.IsAnimating)
                    gifImageView.StopAnimation();
                else
                    gifImageView.StartAnimation();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        };

        btnStart.Click += BtnStart_Click;
        btnStop.Click += BtnStop_Click;

    }

    private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gifImageView.StopAnimation();
    }

    private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gifImageView.StartAnimation();
    }

    private byte[] ConvertByteArray(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]